# Masters thesis topics in big data

Tags: bigdata, apache-hadoop, research

I am looking for a thesis to complete my master M2, I will work on a topic in the big data's field (creation big data applications), using hadoop/mapReduce and Ecosystem ( visualisation, analysis ...), Please suggest some topics or project that would make for a good masters thesis subject.
I add that I have bases in data warehouses, databases, data mining, good skills in programming, system administration and cryptography ...

Thanks

Comment: This is too broad to be a useful question. Narrow it down by stating what you have studied, your interests, and some specific topics you are considering.

Comment: thanks @SeanOwen. good, i will add some other information about my studies on Master and my interests :)

Comment: "and beyond" part of [this](http://www.meetup.com/spark-users/events/175940092/) and/or [this](http://www.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/th-210p212meng) is probably a good point to start.

Comment: You might wanna state that Big Data is a leading trend in the Computer industry.

Comment: You are paying to do a Masters, what do your tutors suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's a master's thesis, how about writing something regarding decision trees, and their "upgrades": boosting and Random Forests? And then integrate that with Map/Reduce, together with showing how to scale a Random Forest on Hadoop using M/R?

Comment: thanks @ssantic , I will consider your proposal for to know the dimensions of this subject according to my ability